# for each loop in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, for-loop, c++14

When I practising the sort algorithm, find a weird issue about `for each`. I'm not sure where it goes wrong, so post the entire code in below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <class T, class U = std::greater<>> // std::greater<> require C++14
void bubbleSort(T begin, T end, U comp = U())
{
    for(auto i = end; i != begin; i--) {
        for(auto j = begin; j != i; j++) {
            if(comp(*j, *i)) {
                std::swap(*j, *i);
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T, class U = std::greater<>> // std::greater<> require C++14
void bubbleSort2(T begin, T end, U comp = U())
{
    auto low = begin;
    auto high = end;
    while(low < high) {
        for(auto i = low; i != high; i++) {
            if(comp(*i, *(i + 1))) {
                std::swap(*i, *(i + 1));
            }
        }
        high--;
        for(auto i = high; i != low; i--) {
            if(comp(*(i - 1), *i)) {
                std::swap(*i, *(i - 1));
            }
        }
        low++;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem comes:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> s = {5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3};
    bubbleSort(s.begin(), s.end());

    for(auto i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) // Loop1
        std::cout << s.at(i) << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto a : s) { // Loop2
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At first, I only wrote the `Loop2` to test the output, but I observed the output is: `0 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`. then I add the `Loop1`, the output becomes correct:
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. I think there shall be something wrong in sort function, but why adding `Loop1` could fix it?
(both two sort got the same behaviour)

The compiler is mingw32.

Thanks to @FeiXiang's comment, put the fixed code at [GitHub](https://github.com/arkceajin/algorithm-practice/blob/master/bubblesort.h)

And @Aconcagua's recommendtion, change to:

```
template <class T, class U = std::greater<>> // std::greater<> require C++14
void bubbleSort3(T begin, T end, U comp = U())
{
    while(end != begin) {
        for(auto i = std::next(begin); i != end; ++i)
            if(comp(*(i - 1), *i))
                std::swap(*(i - 1), *i);
        end--;
    }
}
```

Comment: You dereferenced the end iterator in your bubble sort function, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Just a matter of theory (both are O(n^2)), I think it's rather selection sort than bubble sort (first variant), bubble sort would swap *neighbouring* elements, you swap elements of arbitrary distance...

Comment: In you second variant, you just "gain" code complexity, but you don't reduce number of comparisons by the second loop. I'd recommend just dropping it, solely having `while(end != begin) { for(auto i = std::next(begin), i != end; ++i) comp(*(i-1), *i);} --begin; }`

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks, I will be trying to compare the actual time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

"i" should start from "end-1"

```
for(auto i = end-1; i != begin; i--)
```

cause "end" points to next pos of the last element in array.